# Calculate the number of items within the a Shopping Cart

Tags: java, list, dictionary, cart

I am quite new to the concepts of Java. I have designed a shopping cart application using core java. But i am not able to get the desired output.
Here is my pojo class item.java

```
package com.shop.data.*;
public class Item
{
    private int Itemid;
    private String category;
    private String name;
    private double price;
      private String size;

    /**
     * @return the category
     */
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
    public Item(int itemid) {
        super();
        Itemid = itemid;
    }
    /**
     * @param category the category to set
     */
    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a new item with the given attributes.
    // -------------------------------------------------------
    public Item (String itemcategory ,String itemName, double itemPrice,String itemSize)
    {
        name = itemName;
        price = itemPrice;

        size = itemSize;
        category = itemcategory;
    }
    public Item(String itemName, int itemPrice, String size) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @return the size
     */
    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    /**
     * @param size the size to set
     */
    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the unit price of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------
    //   Returns the name of the item
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the itemid
     */
    public int getItemid() {
        return Itemid;
    }
    /**
     * @param itemid the itemid to set
     */
    public void setItemid(int itemid) {
        Itemid = itemid;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String toString ()
    {

        return (name + "\t" + price +  "\t"+ size +  "\t");
    }


}
```

The main class is ShopCartTest.java

```
package com.shop.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.shop.data.*;

public class ShoppingCartTest {
    private static Scanner scan;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // *** declare and instantiate a variable cart to be an empty ArrayList
        shopping();
    }

    public static void shopping() {
        ArrayList<Item> ItemCart = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Map<Item, Integer> Quantity = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
        Item item = null;
        Inventory inventory = null;
        String category = null;
        String itemName;
        String itemSize;
        double itemPrice = 0;
        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        double sum = 0.0;
        int itemquantity;
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String keepShopping = "y";
        System.out.println("****Shopping Cart****");
        do {
            System.out.println("Select Category: ");
            category = scan.nextLine();
            if (category.equals("men") || category.equals("Men")) {

                System.out
                        .println("Available Items: \n1Shirt : 900 \n2.T-Shirt : 700 \n3.Jean: 1500.\n");
                System.out.println("Select Item to Add to your Bag: ");
                itemName = scan.nextLine();
                if (itemName.equals("Shirt") || (itemName.equals("shirt"))) {
                    itemPrice = 900;
                } else if (itemName.equals("T-Shirt")
                        || (itemName.equals("t-shirt"))) {
                    itemPrice = 700;
                } else
                    itemPrice = 1500;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Available Items: \n1.Dress : 250 \n2.Top : 350 \n3.Jean: 1500.\n");
                System.out.println("Select Item to Add to your Bag: ");
                itemName = scan.nextLine();
                // *** create a new item and add it to the cart
                if (itemName.equals("Dress") || (itemName.equals("dress"))) {
                    itemPrice = 250;
                } else if (itemName.equals("Top") || (itemName.equals("top"))) {
                    itemPrice = 350;
                } else
                    itemPrice = 1500;
            }
            System.out.print("Available Sizes \nS \tM \tL: ");
            itemSize = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the quantity: ");
            itemquantity = scan.nextInt();
            item = new Item(category, itemName, itemPrice, itemSize);
            ItemCart.add(item);
            Quantity.put(item, itemquantity); 

            // *** print the contents of the cart object using println
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemCart.size(); i++) {
                Item itm = ItemCart.get(i);
                System.out.println(itm);
            }

            // Print out the results
            System.out.print("Continue shopping (y/n)? ");
            scan.nextLine();
            keepShopping = scan.nextLine();
        } while (keepShopping.equals("y"));

        for (int i = 0; i < ItemCart.size(); i++) {
            Quantity.put(item, itemquantity);
            Item itm = ItemCart.get(i);
            System.out.println(itm);
            totalPrice = itemquantity * itm.getPrice();
            for (int j = 0; i < ItemCart.size(); i++)
                sum += totalPrice;

        }

        System.out.println("The total price is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Do you wan to proceed to checkout (y/n): ");
        if (scan.nextLine().equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("Thank you for shopping with us!");

        } else {
            shopping();
        }

    }

}
```

There are 4 pojo's Cart, inventory,Item, User. The user must be able to select multiple items of multiple quanties. (*For items a list is been created and for the quantity: map. where item object is the key and quantity is the value*). The user slects category, item, then quatity. Then he can proceed to checkout. So when he decides to checkout. He must be able to see the various items purchased ie (itemName, SIxe ,UnitPrice, unitprice*quantity) and finally the Total Price. 
How do i achieve this? I am kinda lost!

Comment: You can always map the User with onetomany for CartItems. And the CartItems mapped to manyToOne with Inventory. I would recommend to save the User's cartItems in database, so that if there is power loss or user logs out, the cart still remains.

Comment: Apart from your question, try to divide your methods into more smaller methods to add readability

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

- You should use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) (i.e. variables and methods name starts with a lower case letter)
- `ItemCart` is redundant, you can remove it and use the *keys* of `Quantity`
- a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) provides an [`entrySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) method, using that on `Quantity` will help you list the items in the cart (*keys*) and compute the total price using the item (*key*) price and quantity (*value*)

Comment: Hi Sir, Can you please give me an example code for the same. ?